# asyncio/aiohttp - How to make series of async - but dependent - requests?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a sequence of pairs of async requests in which a pair consists of Request A and Request B. Additionally, Request B is dependent on Request A. In other words, I need to pass data from Response A into Request B. Therefore, I need to schedule tasks such that each task sends Request A, then sends Request B only after Response A has returned.

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from typing import *
import asyncio

async def request_A(url: str, session: ClientSession) -> dict:
    async with session.request('get', url) as response:
        return await response.json()

async def request_B(url: str, data: dict, session: ClientSession) -> dict:
    async with session.request('post', url, json=data) as response:
        return await response.json()

async def request_chain(url_A: str, url_B: str, session: ClientSession) -> dict:
    response_A_data = await request_A(url_A, session)
    response_B_data = await request_B(url_B, response_A_data, session)
    return response_B_data

async def schedule(url_chains: List[Tuple[str, str]]) -> list:
    tasks = []
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for url_chain in url_chains:
            url_A, url_B = url_chain
            task = asyncio.create_task(request_chain(url_A, url_B, session))
            tasks.append(task)
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

def run_tasks(url_chains: List[Tuple[str, str]]) -> list:
    return asyncio.run(schedule(url_chains))
```

Now, my question: Per each task consisting of a pair of requests, is Request A guaranteed to return before Request B is sent? Please explain. I am concerned that within the task, while Request A is being awaited, Request B may execute.

If not, how can I keep the tasks async and non-blocking, but also ensure that within the task, Request A blocks execution of Request B until Response A has returned?

I understand that I can run all Request A calls in a batch, then run all Request B calls in a batch, but for reasons specific to my use case, I need to run a batch of all (Request A, Request B) pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Per each task consisting of a pair of requests, is Request A
>   guaranteed to return before Request B is sent?

Yes, the advantage of the async/await pattern is that you don't have to ask yourself this question, consecutives lines of code will always be executed sequentially (**but not necessarily consecutively**). Here your function `request_chain` guarantees that `request_A` will always be executed before `request_B`.

> while Request A is being awaited, Request B may execute

That won't happen, that's basically what `await` means : *hang on until request A has returned before going any further*. In other words, `await` has no impact on execution order. It just *hands the control* so hiddle time can be used by *someone else* (in your case, any code from another *(A, B)* request pair). That's essentially why consecutives lines of code are **not necessarily executed consecutively**, handing control to some other [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) (the *someone else* we just mentioned) using `await` allow this coroutine to execute code between A and B.

Even if that's a bit inaccurate, you can remember that: The only code that will be executed in parallel is the one you schedule yourself (in this case using `asyncio.gather`, scheduling several *(A, B) pairs* to be executed in parallel).

> I understand that I can run all Request A calls in a batch, then run all Request B calls in a batch, but for reasons specific to my use case, I need to run a batch of all ...

In this particular case, even if you could run a batch of *A*'s then a batch of *B*'s, I think your solution would be better as it highlights in a simpler way the relation between *A* and *B*.

Here is a sample of code that you can run to try things out (it does the same as what you do here with a public math API), it simply compute "x*2+2" in two steps, first "*2" (equivalent of request *A*), then "+2" (equivalent of request *B*):

```py
MATH_API_URL = "http://api.mathjs.org/v4"

from aiohttp import ClientSession
import asyncio

async def maths(session, url, expression):
    params = {"expr" : expression}
    print(f"\t> computing {expression}")
    async with session.get(url, params=params) as response:
        result = await response.text()
        print(f"\t< {expression} = {result}")
        return result

async def twice(session, x):
    return await maths(session, MATH_API_URL, f"2 * {x}")

async def plus_two(session, x):
    return await maths(session, MATH_API_URL, f"2 + {x}")

async def twice_plus_two(session, x):
    twice_x = await twice(session, x)
    return await plus_two(session, twice_x)

async def main(inputs):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        return await asyncio.gather(*(twice_plus_two(session, x) for x in inputs))

inputs = list(range(3))
print([x*2+2 for x in inputs])
print(asyncio.run(main(inputs)))
```

This code outputs the order in which requests are scheduled :

```
[2, 4, 6]    
    > computing 2 * 0    
    > computing 2 * 1    
    > computing 2 * 2    
    < 2 * 1 = 2    
    > computing 2 + 2
    < 2 * 0 = 0    
    > computing 2 + 0
    < 2 * 2 = 4    
    > computing 2 + 4
    < 2 + 2 = 4    
    < 2 + 4 = 6
    < 2 + 0 = 2
['2', '4', '6']
```

See how the "+2" are scheduled as soon as the "*2" have returned.

Comment: Thank you! Cleared up my confusion greatly.